# storage link no funciona en hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

En mi proyecto local. guardo las imagenes en el storage path y cargo normalmente con asset('storage/...');

Todo sin problemas.
Al hosting que lo tengo que subir no tengo accesso total. solo acceso mediante ftp,tampoco acceso ssh.
Cuando se descompacta el proyecto en el hosting, el storage link en el carpeta public , trae todos los archivos como un carpeta. La elimine y entonces como no tengo ssh declare una ruta para ejecutar el comando.

```
Route::get('storage-link', function(){
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
   echo (Artisan::output());
});
```

Al correr la ruta incluso me imprime el mensaje que normalmente muestra cuando se corre el comando en consola diciendo que se creo el enlace entre las carpetas.

El problema es que en realidad no se muestran las imagenes.

```
asset('/storage/cars/photo.jpg')
```

si paso la carpeta para public y la llamo sin pasar por el vinculo asset('/cars/photo.jpg') la muestra correctamente.

Espero me puedan ayudar . gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedo resolver el problema??? Tengo la misma situación

Answer (score 0):

Intenté con varias opciones y no me funcionó. Esto pasa porque en un hosting compartido la carpeta se llama public_html; después de varios intentos con diferentes opciones me sirvió lo siguiente:

Accede por ssh al servidor, ejecuta la terminal y en el folder public_html coloca el comando:

ln -s ../storage/app/public ./storage

asi creas el enlace simbolico desde la carpeta public hacia la carpeta donde tienes el resto del codigo de laravel

Url para mas informacion:

https://dejuniorasenior.com/laravel-8-enlace-de-almacenamiento-storage-link-no-funciona-en-produccion/

Saludos,
Deios

Comment: Saludos @Deios, las respuestas que son solo links son considerados de baja calidad, por favor agrega las partes que consideres importantes que se encuentran en la página linkeada, recuerda que si por alguna razón la página linkeada desaparece tu respuesta quedaría inservible. ;)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).